# JQuery UI - Slider change opacity on slide - Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider, opacity

I'm trying to use a JQueryUI slider to control the opacity of an element with the id "main-lights", but this script causes an error.

```
$("#slider-lamps").slider({
orientation: "vertical", 
range: "min",
value: 50,
min: 0,
max: 100
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#main-lights" ).css( "opacity", ui.values[ 0 ]);
}
});
```

This version works fine:

```
$("#slider-lamps").slider({
orientation: "vertical", 
range: "min",
value: 50,
min: 0,
max: 100
});
```

Can I not use a variable as the second jquery .css parameter?

How can I write this properly?

Comment: What error do you get? Please post the HTML as well, and a jsFiddle if you would.

Comment: your missing a `,` after `max:100` in your first code segment.

Comment: Ah, I usually just error check with the fact that my page's javascript doesn't work. I'll put a js fiddle together I guess

Comment: Might as well post it as an answer that fixed it. The easiest things are the worst

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a missing comma (typo).


Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `,` after `max:100` in your first code segment.

```
$("#slider-lamps").slider({
    orientation: "vertical", 
    range: "min",
    value: 50,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#main-lights" ).css( "opacity", ui.values[ 0 ]);
    }
});
```

Comment: @jt0dd please mark this answer as accepted if it was helpful, Or remove your question if you feel its not relevant anymore.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#slider-lamps").slider({
orientation: "vertical", 
range: "min",
value: 50,
min: 0,
max: 100**,**
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#main-lights" ).css( "opacity", ui.values[ 0 ]);
}
});
```

You missed a "," after max:100

Comment: This is the same as Trevor's answer.

Comment: Removing it! Saw it just now!